# Catch button pressure duration

Tags: ios, swift, ibaction

I am building an app in which, one of the function is to press a button that will send an emotion to my server so that I can use it. The concept is easy: the longer the button is pressed, the bigger the emotion is.

In order to do that, I actually need to catch how long this button is pressed and I don't really have a serious clue about how I could do this.

I'm "new" in `Swift` programming that's why I'm asking for help, or just an advice! I already did the basic elements, such as creating the button, the class for my `viewcontroller`, the `IBAction`. But I read a bit about the `NSTimer` variables but without truly getting the point of it.

Comment: Hi Louis Guislain.
It is always important to put some code in your post to give us more information about our issue.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom class, which will extend `UIView` and implement it as follows:

```
class Some: UIView{

var start: Date?
var lastDuration: TimeInterval?{
    didSet{
        // Call the methods you need
        // At this point the value of lastDuration
        // is the value you need
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    self.start = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

    if let start = self.start{
        self.lastDuration = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0).timeIntervalSince(start)
    }
}
}
```

This should work, let me know

Comment: Hi ! First of all thanks for your answer ! About the piece of code you just wrote, I have two questions. First one is just out of curiosity, why exactly the two functions have to be overriden ?
Second, here `[...] with event: UIEvent?` Should i just let it like this or should it actually be replaced by an actual event ? 
I assume that since `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` take both as argument an event, there should be somehow two properties that would mean in rough words "i started pressing" and "i released the button". What would those be ? 
Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @LouisGuislain 
First: you override the functions to add the desirable functionality to it. You might add `UIGestureRecognizer`s as well, but this is the most convenient way.
Second: Yes, it actually would be more correct if we payed attention to what events are happening and what touches trigger the methods. You may implement this if you wish, but I think that it is not necessary, since it would only cause problems on odd occasions like if the user would use one finger to press and the other to press again or swipe. To avoid that keep a `touch` attribute and compare that to what's ended

Comment: Hi there, I kinda don't really get how exactly I should use these methods. Are they simply implemented here and should be called afterwards, in a different place ? How exactly Can I get the value representing the time between the beginning of the pressure and the release of the button ?

Comment: @LouisGuislain These methods are called by the system itself and that's their beauty. And as soon as there's a new duration value, the marked scope will be called, there you can implement the desired functionality